# Unexpected result in a simple formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've tried the following formula y Excel 2013 (desktop version) and Excel Online and both return the same weird result. However I've tried it with Google Sheets and it returns the expected result in all cases.

Cells:

```
A2 = 1937.7
C1 = 20
```

In cell B2 I get the fractional part of the number in A2 and it works OK

```
B2 =   =(A2-INT(A2))*100
```

Here's the problem:

```
C2 =   =INT(B2/C1)
```

When the fraction in A2 is 7 the result is the expected (3) but when the fraction is 8 the result is still 3 when the expected is 4.

Now if I change the integer part of A2 to 1 then there's no problem at all in any case.

Here's the link to the Excel sheet https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=737F94B0DCBC9094!5483&authkey=!ABfKYkDITdITGqE&ithint=file%2cxlsx

Comment: you can see the mentioned rounding error from Ron's answer when click on the Formulas tab, in the Formula Auditing group, click Evaluate Formula. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Evaluate-a-nested-formula-one-step-at-a-time-59a201ae-d1dc-4b15-8586-a70aa409b8a7?fromAR=1&omkt=en-001&ui=en-US&rs=en-001&ad=US

Comment: @FalcoAlexander thank you very much for the tip about how to evaluate a formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have run into what has been termed "rounding errors".  A2-int(a2) cannot be expressed exactly as 0.8 under the IEEE standard for double precision numbers that Excel and most computer spreadsheet programs use.  It gets stored as something like 0.799999999999955.

You can correct the problem by rounding to the desired level of precision.

eg:

```
B2: =ROUND((A2-INT(A2))*100,0)
```

See [Floating Point Arithmetic may give inaccurate results in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/78113)

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response. I tried your solution and still I can't believe it! How Excel will use IEEE 754 to do calculations? OMG

Comment: @vcRobe It has to do with the impossibility of storing certain fractions as binary numbers, which is all computers can do